# Efficient calculations in MS SQL Server with varying number of inputs

Tags: sql-server

Without the ability to use arrays in my MS SQL stored proc, I'm having trouble figuring out an efficient way to calculate a formula.

Background....

```
select child_id, sum(quantity) as quantity 
    from table 
    where parent_id = @parent_id
```

returns something like this....

```
child_id     quantity
100           50000
200           60000
300           45000
400           30000
500           15000
```

This is a simplified SQL formula to illustrate what I need help with.  The mathematics aren't important (okay if it doesn't make sense -- it's simplified to show how I need to use the summed quantities from above)...

```
set @result = (2 * LOG(50000)) + LOG(60000) + LOG(45000) + LOG(30000) + LOG(15000)
```

For each of the above child_id, I want to execute a (select child_id, @result).  Note that the summed quantity for the "active" child_id is treated differently than that of the other child_ids (2*LOG()).  Also, the count of child_id is variable between 2 and 20.  If there were only 2 child_ids, @result would be = (2*LOG(50000) + LOG(60000).

I hope that makes sense.  Thank you much for any suggestions you can offer.

Comment: In the above example, what would be the result for child_id 200?

Comment: Matt, Joe, Martin - thank you.  I'll have to think about it some more to know for sure if the CTE approach will work (or how it will work) with my non-simplifed algorithm.  Matt, to answer your question -- the result for child_id 200 would be =(2*LOG(60000))+LOG(50000)+LOG(45000)+LOG(30000)+LOG(15000).   Thanks again guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming at least SQL 2005 for the [CTEs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx). The method of my madness is that I'll get a single sum for all the log values, then add in the log value for each child to achieve the 2*(this child's value) portion of the sum.

```
;with cteQuantity as (
    select child_id, sum(quantity) as quantity 
        from table 
        where parent_id = @parent_id
        group by child_id
),
cteAllLogs as (
    select sum(log(quantity)) as log_sum
        from cteQuantity
)
select q.child_id, log(q.quantity) + l.log_sum as result
    from cteQuantity q
        cross join cteAllLogs l
```

Comment: Yeah, we're thinking along the same lines. It's reassuring we're coming up with the same answer :) @karman, Joe's CTE is probably the cleaner way to go, assuming you're not struggling along with SQL Server 2000 or anything.

Comment: Thanks again guys.  I was able to get Joe's CTE example to work with my complete algorithm and I'm pleased with the query plans.  High-Five!

Answer (score 1):

Well, this might head you in the right direction, but we might need a bit more detail about the calculations:

```
DROP TABLE #results
CREATE TABLE #results (parent_id INTEGER, child_id INTEGER, quantity FLOAT)
INSERT INTO #results VALUES (10, 100, 50000)
INSERT INTO #results VALUES (10, 200, 60000)
INSERT INTO #results VALUES (10, 300, 45000)
INSERT INTO #results VALUES (10, 400, 30000)
INSERT INTO #results VALUES (10, 500, 15000)

SELECT 
    child_id, quantity, LOG(quantity) + (SELECT SUM(LOG(quantity)) FROM #results subquery WHERE #results.parent_id = subquery.parent_id)
FROM
    #results
```

Comment: You could also use a windowed aggregate function rather than a sub query though I'm still somewhat unsure about the efficiency of these `SELECT child_id,quantity, LOG(quantity) + SUM(LOG(quantity)) OVER () FROM #results`

Comment: @Martin Yup. As long as there are appropriate indexes in place, I reckon they'll be doing about the same amount of work, so I'm not sure there'll be a lot to choose. But it'll be hard to tell without looking at the query plans or measuring it.